# Objective C: write a NSMutableString in a csv (txt)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, string, nsmutablestring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [objective C: write in a csv (txt) string contained in some textfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569396/objective-c-write-in-a-csv-txt-string-contained-in-some-textfield)

I have a NSMutableString "stringForCsv", and I must write it in a csv file (txt) what the code for to do it? The file is on my project folder.