# Objective C: write string on csv file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, string, csv, writetofile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [objective C: write in a csv (txt) string contained in some textfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569396/objective-c-write-in-a-csv-txt-string-contained-in-some-textfield)

I have this code to write a string in a csv file (txt) (string to write is : csvString)

```
NSString *resourceFileName = @"Client";
NSString *pathToFile =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: resourceFileName ofType: @"txt"];
NSError *error;

NSString *fileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pathToFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if (!fileString) {
    NSLog(@"Error reading file.");
} 



[csvString writeToFile:pathToFile atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

but it don't work, why?