# Objective C: write string on csv file

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablestring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [objective C: write in a csv (txt) string contained in some textfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569396/objective-c-write-in-a-csv-txt-string-contained-in-some-textfield)

I have this code to write a string in a csv file (txt)

```
NSMutableString *csvString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:textfield1.text];
[csvString appendString:@"#"];
[csvString appendString:textfield2.text];
[csvString appendString:@"#"];
[csvString appendString:dtextfield3.text];
[csvString appendString:@"#"];
[csvString appendString:textfield4.text];
[csvString appendString:@"#"];
[csvString appendString:textfield5.text];
[csvString appendString:@"#"];
[csvString appendString:textfield6.text];
[csvString appendString:@"#"];
[csvString appendString:textfield7.text];
[csvString appendString:@"#"];
if (uiswitch.on) { //switch
[csvString appendString:@"1"];
}
else [csvString appendString:@"0"];
[csvString appendString:@";"];

NSString *resourceFileName = @"Client";
NSString *pathToFile =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: resourceFileName ofType: @"txt"];
NSError *error;

NSString *fileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pathToFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if (!fileString) {
NSLog(@"Error reading file.");
} 

[csvString writeToFile:pathToFile atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

But it don't work, why???